# How to communicate with Android from a PC via wi-fi?

Tags: android

I want to write a program ,which will communicate to the available android mobile device via wi-fi .(Note :I do not want to use the USB cable)

That moblile device is having an IP in it by a wi-fi connection with it.The major thing is that i pinged that IP and I am getting connection packets getting back to my pc,means I can communicate with the devices. so can I able to get the details of the device.

details means
1.its name what user sets on it.
2.some address like mac in computers.
3.model name.
4.type of os in it.
etc

I really find this interesting but,no idea how to do but i got something like ARP protocol for getting the mac address but I do not know how to communicate with a phone with this ARP protocol.

Can we communicate by the SSH as it a linux kernel based OS .Kindly give me a way how to get these information.

can any one have some idea ,kindly tell me,it is very important for my project.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is [adbWireless](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=siir.es.adbWireless&hl=pl) application. If you install it on your device, a widget appears that allows you to connect with it over WiFi. In Toast message it shows IP address of Android device.

Then on your PC type:

```
adb connect 192.168.1.102
```

(replace it with Android IP address).

And now you have an access to your phone over WiFi (check it with `adb devices`).

You need rooted phone to use `adbWireless`.

Comment: Thanks,for the information I have doubts as I do not want an application to run on android device.I want a program that should communicate with the device.I got socket programming but for this also clien-sever needed which i do not want.Is there any protocol used for this to simply get the details from an android device.I want is there a way to communicate and get the information.Also is there is a way to coomunicate via SSH protocol.

Comment: You can access device with `adb shell`. Also there is `Dropbear` SSH server for Android. Here is howto: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Howto:_Connect_to_Device_with_SSH

Comment: Hi,I have some doubt.I got the link you have given but is it possible to connect to the android from a linux directly with out  the keygen file.I know how to use ssh but it will ask the password so how to use this passowrd thing and I donot want to use the key file as the link suggested.simply i know the IP and password and I want to connect to the android.Can you tell me how can i set this password for the android as we are creating for Linux OS to access via SSH.Also I do not want to install the adb for this.Is there is a way to do this.